# Android - GregorianCalendar determine if a day belongs to the current month

Tags: android, calendar, gregorian-calendar

I am making a calendar using a GridView and a custom BaseAdapter. I use a GregorianCalendar in a function to generate a string array of days in order to populate the cells. Here is the my MainActivity which handles the layout of the Calendar:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GridView calendarView, daysView;
    private final String[] weekdays = new String[]{"Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat","Sun"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        daysView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.daysGridView);
        daysView.setAdapter(new WeekDayGridAdapter(MainActivity.this, weekdays));

        calendarView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.calendarGridView);
        calendarView.setAdapter(new DayGridAdapter(MainActivity.this, getMonth()));
    }

    private String[] getMonth(){

        int gridSizeX = 7, gridSizeY = 6;
        int gridsize = gridSizeX * gridSizeY;
        String[] myStringArray = new String[gridSizeX*gridSizeY];

        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);

        GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, 1);
        //this gets the day of week range 1-7, Monday - Sunday
        int dayOfWeek = gregorianCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        //backtracks to the beginning of current week (Monday)
        gregorianCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, Calendar.MONDAY - dayOfWeek);

        for (int i = 0; i < gridsize; i++)
            {
                myStringArray[i] = String.valueOf(gregorianCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                gregorianCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
            }
        return myStringArray;
    }
}
```

And here is how my Calendar looks:
[image: November 2013]

What i want is a way to determine which cells belong to the previous or the next month relative to the current month. In the case of the image above that cells will be:

- the first 4
- the last 9

Comment: Get every date between 1 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive).

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Thanks. I changed my BaseAdapter based on your logic and it works just fine. I will post the code.

Comment: if (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == month) {}

Comment: you assume that the week starts on monday.

Comment: @njzk2 Thanks, i will try what you proposed. Concering your second comment about the starting day of the week, i know it starts on monday. I didn't do it by accindent.

Comment: *in some countries* it starts on monday. Calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek() gives you an absolute value of the first day of the week no matter what, making your code more reusable.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it based on JeroenVannevel's comment.

> Get every date between 1 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive)

Here is my custom BaseAdapter:

```
public class DayGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private final String[] days;

    // global var to keep track of whether a day-cell belongs to the current month
    Boolean in = false;

    public DayGridAdapter(Context context, String[] days) {
        this.context = context;
        this.days = days;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View gridView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            gridView = new View(context);
            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.day_gridcell, null);

            // coming from the previous month and encounter (for the first time) the cell "1"
            if(days[position].equals("1") && in == false){
                in = true;
            }
            // coming from the current month and encounter (for the second time) the cell "1"
            else if (days[position].equals("1") && in == true){
                in = false;
            }

            Button button = (Button) gridView.findViewById(R.id.day_grid_item);
            button.setText(days[position]);

            if(in){
                //white background color
                button.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            }else {
                //light grey background color
                button.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.ligth2));
            }

        } else {
            gridView = convertView;
        }
        return gridView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return days.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And here is how it looks now:
[image]

Comment: There is no guarantee that the item views are created in sequence. this will fail on a small screen device.

Comment: not to mention that your handling of view recycling does not handle anything.

Answer (score 0):

I did this very thing quite some time ago on a quick project (so it isn't optimized).  This is my GridAdapter (your DayGridAdapter)

```
public class CalendarGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context _context;
    public String[] _days;
    int _startPosition;
    int _endPosition;

    private java.util.Calendar _month;

    public CalendarGridAdapter(Context c, Calendar monthCalendar) {
        _month = monthCalendar;
        _context = c;
        _month.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

        refreshDays();
    }


    public int getCount() {
        return _days.length; //(42) 6 weeks
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * Creates the calendar date view, using the correct background based on the month the date
     * is in
     */
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView dateView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_day, null);
        }

        dateView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.calendar_day_date);

        //Sets the background
        if(position < _startPosition -1 || position > _endPosition -1)
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_day_unselected_month_background);
        else convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_day_selected_month_background);

        dateView.setText(_days[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

    //Assumes the first day of the week is Sunday
    public void refreshDays() {
        int lastDay = _month.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int firstDay = _month.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        _startPosition = firstDay;

        //determines size of the "week" array
        int size = firstDay == 1 ? lastDay : (lastDay + firstDay -1);
        _endPosition = size;
        _days = new String[42]; //6 weeks
        int j;

        //populate the beginning of the calendar with the previous months days when appropriate
        Calendar prevMonth = (Calendar)_month.clone();
        int prevLastDay = previousMonthDays(prevMonth);
        for(j = 0; j < firstDay; j++)
            _days[j] = "" + (prevLastDay - firstDay + j +2);

        // populate selected months days
        int dayNumber = 1;
        for(int i = j-1; i < size; i++)
            _days[i] = "" + dayNumber++;

        //next month days (need a total of 6 rows)
        for(int i = size; i < 42; i++)
            _days[i] = "" + (i - size + 1);
    }

    private int previousMonthDays(Calendar calendar) {
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MONTH)) {
            calendar.set((calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)-1),calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.MONTH),1);
        } else {
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)-1);
        }

        return calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }
}
```

Basically I create an array to list all the days that are visible, then check which day of the week is the first and last day of the current (selected) month.  The other days will then be given a different background.

Then since you passed a reference to the `Calendar monthCalendar` any changes you make to that will be reflected in the CalendarGridAdapter.

You can modify months by the following (_selectedMonth is your Calendar)

```
public void previousMonth() {
    if(_selectedMonth.get(Calendar.MONTH) == _selectedMonth.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MONTH)) {
        _selectedMonth.set((_selectedMonth.get(Calendar.YEAR)-1),_selectedMonth.getActualMaximum(Calendar.MONTH),1);
    } else {
        _selectedMonth.set(Calendar.MONTH, _selectedMonth.get(Calendar.MONTH)-1);
    }

    refreshCalendar();
}

public void nextMonth() {
    if(_selectedMonth.get(Calendar.MONTH)== _selectedMonth.getActualMaximum(Calendar.MONTH)) {
        _selectedMonth.set((_selectedMonth.get(Calendar.YEAR)+1),_selectedMonth.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MONTH),1);
    } else {
        _selectedMonth.set(Calendar.MONTH,_selectedMonth.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
    }

    refreshCalendar();
}

public void refreshCalendar() {
        _calendarAdapter.refreshDays();
        _calendarAdapter.setItems(days == null ? new HashSet<Integer>() : days);
        _calendarAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have the current month, that's `month`. You know how to get the month for a date, that `calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)`. You only need to compare the 2 :

```
if (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == month) {
    // Same month
} else {
    // Not same month
}
```

### Edit

The thing here is that you precompute the days before giving them to the adapter, loosing some information at the same time. You should instead have something like *in the getView()*:

```
// Create a calendar for your month/year (these parameters you can pass to the adapter with little modifications)
GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, 1);
// Move back to the first day of the week (could be sunday)
gregorianCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, gregorianCalendar.getFirstDayOfWeek());
// Move by *position*, being the index of the cell.
gregorianCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, position);
String day = String.valueOf(gregorianCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
// Check the month for this particular day
if (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == month) {
    // Same month
} else {
    // Not same month
}
```